# The word "answers" can't fit in the div under questions tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Here is an example: [questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=questions).

(Chrome, OS X)

[image: answers overflow]

Comment: Related - http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8090/favorites-page-answers-text-spilling-outside-its-box

Comment: Specifically this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253458